Org-Agenda: Show only Weekend Days - for a configurable time span, not only for next weekend
Use case: Plan future weekends by using a limited distraction agenda view only showing future Saturdays and Sundays.
I have found solutions for exactly one future weekend but not for a configurable time span, see Org-Agenda: Show Weekend Days (only)
As I cannot yet add comments I am picking up the topic:
Does anybody have an org-agenda-custom-commands config covering this use case?
